# How to get map from list of object using stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have class country:

```
class Country {
private String code;
private String name;
}
```

I need to do from list of Countries to Map with code and name.
I tried to

```
Map<String, String> countryNames = countries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getCode, Country::getName));
```

But it is not right. How to collect correct?

Comment: `countries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getCode, Country::getName));`

Comment: Do you want to use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function))

Comment: it does not work UPD: it's okey, my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want `code` as the key and name as the `value`. In that case, you need to use `Collectors.mapping` as the downstream collector to `Collectors.groupingBy`. Like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> countryNames = countries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Country::getCode, 
            Collectors.mapping(Country::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

Note that this will return the values as a list of strings, as the names are grouped in a list (by `Collectors.toList()`) if there are multiple countries with the same code.

If you know that each code only appears once in the list, you can use `Collectors.toMap` instead.

```
Map<String, String> countryNames = countries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getCode, Country::getName));
```

Comment: yep, i tried your first version, forget about second arguement and decided to go here